# Javascript returns NaN only in IOS browsers

Tags: javascript, html, ios, web, nan

I am making this age calculator website which uses the Date object in JS and by subtracting the current time in milliseconds and the user's date of birth in milliseconds calculates their age in different units (years, months, days etc.) and outputs it to the html.

It is completely functional on windows and android, however, when the website is loaded in IOS it returns NaN. I don't know if it has to do with the parseInt() function or something that is done automatically in these two platforms which aren't done in IOS. Here is the website for reference: https://hesamzakeri.ir/en/

```
    <div id="years"></div>
    <div id="months"></div>
    <div id="days"></div>
    <div id="hours"></div>
    <div id="minutes"></div>
    <div id="seconds"></div>

<script>
    let currentTime = Date.now();

    let birthday = new Date(2002 + '-' + 07 + '-' + 04); // example

    let birthday = Date.parse(birthday);

    let age = currentTime - birthday;

    let yearsOld = parseInt(age / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365, 10);

    let yearsOldInMs = yearsOld * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    let monthsOld = parseInt((age - yearsOldInMs) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 30.417, 10);

    let monthsOldInMs = monthsOld * 30.417 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    let daysOld = parseInt((age - (yearsOldInMs + monthsOldInMs)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24, 10);

    let daysOldInMs = daysOld * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    let hoursOld = parseInt((age - (yearsOldInMs + monthsOldInMs + daysOldInMs)) / 1000 / 60 / 60, 10);

    let hoursOldInMs = hoursOld * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    let minutesOld = parseInt((age - (yearsOldInMs + monthsOldInMs + daysOldInMs + hoursOldInMs)) /
                1000 /
                60,
            10
        );

    let minutesOldInMs = minutesOld * 60 * 1000;

    let secondsOld = parseInt(
            (age -
                (yearsOldInMs +
                    monthsOldInMs +
                    daysOldInMs +
                    hoursOldInMs +
                    minutesOldInMs)) /
                1000,
            10
        );
</script>
```

Here is one of the parts where it calculates the age. I omitted the unnecessary parts of the JS such as where it outputs the results to the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that when you use `2002 + '-' + 07 + '-' + 04`  there are two problems, First, When you define a number with a leading zero(0) it considers the number is an octal integer so you can't have like `09` or `08`.
Secondly, If you evaluate `2002 + '-' + 07 + '-' + 04` it will be `2002-7-4` which is not a valid date by the JS spec docs, Chrome and Firefox are smart enough to parse this string as date value but Safari considers this an invalid value.
you can do this instead:

```
let birthday = new Date(2002,7,4);
```

Also, you defined `birthday` twice, so it has to be defined only once.

```
  let birthday = new Date(2002,7,4); // example

  birthday = Date.parse(birthday);
```

Comment: Yea it works, Thank you I didn't realise different browsers are this different.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a Date object into [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), which requires a string.

Your code:

```
birthday = new Date(formYear + '-' + formMonth + '-' + formDay);

birthday = Date.parse(birthday); // NaN
```

Change the last line to:

```
birthday = Date.parse(birthday.toString());
```

Update:

The OP comments that the problem was with the non-standard date string input to `new Date()`, not with the call to `Date.parse()`.

The date string input was fixed, but the call to `Date.parse()` is still wrong (although some browsers may still work with it).

```
// this is correct
birthday = new Date(2001, 2, 4);
console.log(typeof birthday); // object

// this is NOT correct, argument to Date.parse is type 'object'
// (Date.parse argument must be type 'string')
birthday = Date.parse(birthday);

// this is what you want:
let birthTime = birthday.getTime();
```

Date.parse requires a string argument, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Syntax):

> ***dateString***
>   A string representing a simplification of the ISO 8601 calendar date extended format.  (Other formats may be used, but results are implementation-dependent.)

Even with a valid date string to pass to Date.parse, you should avoid using Date.parse completely, as different hosts parse date strings differently. From MDN:

> It is not recommended to use `Date.parse` as until ES5, parsing of strings was entirely implementation dependent. There are still many differences in how different hosts parse date strings, therefore date strings should be manually parsed (a library can help if many different formats are to be accommodated).

Comment: No, the problem was that this format of putting the date is not in the official JS specs. But thank you anyway

Comment: The code is still wrong, you need to fix the `Date.parse` line. See my update above.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the dangers of Date.parse! Thanks I'll use the getTime method.